# Can you eat the Beitza at the Seder?

Tags: halacha, food, passover, passover-seder-hagada, eggs

The Halacha is not to eat roasted meat at the Seder, therfore you can not eat the Zeroa at the Seder. Can you eat the roasted egg (Beitza) at the Seder? (sources)

Comment: The egg on the Ke'ara should be boiled and then browned a bit over a fire.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15996 seeks a source for @Yahu's claim.

Comment: Can you source this halacha?

Comment: @DoubleAA [Shulchan Aruch, OC 476](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40432&st=&pgnum=122). Re. the zeroa specifically, see [here](https://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipDate=4/16/2008). Also, related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/629

Comment: @Fred Sounds like a local minhag to me :)

Comment: More general question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36853

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[*Mishna B'rura* 476:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14169&st=&pgnum=173) and [*Taame Haminhagim* 513](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&st=&pgnum=239) say that one **should** eat it.