# when are the 'extras' (simanim) eaten at the seider, eggs and pomegranate?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, passover-seder-hagada, eating, fruits, eggs

In my family, which follows the customs of Baghdad, it is a custom to eat eggs and pomegranate seeds during the seider. Problem is, nobody knows why, when and what to say.

I can see why the eggs are on the seider plate, such as discussed in this [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15998/hardboiled-eggs-and-salt-water-at-the-seder). None of my haggadoth mark the moment when these simanim should be eaten, and I could not find a commentary in our haggadoth about the blessings that should be used when introducing these simanim. I also could not find this custom discussed in the [halachot of the Ben Ish Chai](http://www.mysefer.com/product.asp?cookiecheck=yes&P_ID=4902)

What source discusses or was the base for the (babylonian jews'?) custom of eating the egg and the seeds of the pomegranates? What is the moment the egg and pomegranate are eaten and what blessing/text accompany them?

Comment: The egg commemorates the karbon chagiggah. It has no bracha accompanying it as it is eaten as part of the meal and is covered by the hamotzi which was made on the matzah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, possible symbolism of eggs are discussed in a different question and answer set, to which you linked.

As for pomegranate, this seems to me to be a likely allusion to the poles of pomegranate wood they used as a spit to roast the korban pesach.  See pesachim daf 74.

We eat the egg at the beginning of shulchan orech. Absent any source to the contrary, I would assume a similar time for pomegranates.  I don't know anything specific to say, but not everything needs a ritual text to recite.

Comment: thank you. Based on your answer I was able to find a corroborating source from http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=2475 . I'm beginning to wonder whether pomegranates are part of the baghdadi minhag at all as I can't find any reference to it, but your answer makes a lot of sense

Comment: Pomegranate is a siman of the 613 commandments of the Torah. The culmination of the process started on Pesach is the giving of the Torah on Shavuot. It is all one 'hemshech'.