# Eggs in Salt Water at the Seder

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, yetziat-mitzrayim, egypt, eggs, salt

[Minhagei Yeshurun](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33772&st=&pgnum=82&hilite=) (119) writes

> היה אסור לכהני מצרים עפ"י דתם לאכול מלח לזה צוו חז"ל לאכלו בפסח בסעודה
>   זו למען עשות נגד חקיהם  טעם אכילת תחלה בצים מבושלות הוא גם כן למען
>   עשות נגד חוקי המצרים כי המצרים לא אכלו ביצה ובשר (אבן עזרא וארא) ואין
>   הטעם מפני אבילות על החורבן כי למה דוקא בפסח וכן איתא בשערי רחמים
>   מהגר"א שח"ו להזכיר אבילות ט'ב בפסח ונתן שם טעם אחר

saying the reason for dipping eggs in saltwater at the Pesach Seder is because the Egyptians would eat neither salt nor eat eggs/meat. Why would the Egyptians avoid salt and eggs/meat?

(If possible, where is the quoted Ibn Ezra?)

Comment: The Ibn Ezra on Sh'mot 8:22 reads וכלם הם בני חם ואינם אוכלים בשר עד היום. גם דם וחלב ודג ובצים. והכלל כל דבר שיצא מן החי והם מתעבים מי שיאכל אותם https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.8.22?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Ibn_Ezra_on_Exodus.8.22&lang2=bi so they were vegetarians, but I don't see mention of salt.

Comment: @rosends Thank you! It sounds like they were vegans from the Ibn Ezra that they also didn't eat fish, eggs, or milk...

Comment: The whole pesach tisha bav connection is based off the Shulchan Aruch ,the At Bash of all days of pesach is kneged all yomtovim

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15998

Answer (score 2):

I found it. It's an Ibn Ezra in Shemot 8:22.
ולפי דעתי כי אנשי מצרים בימי משה היו על דעת אנשי לנדיא''ה שהם יותר מחצי העולם וכלם הם בני חם ואינם אוכלים בשר עד היום. גם דם וחלב ודג ובצים.

Meaning that the Egyptians didn't eat any meat, milk, fish, or eggs. Doesn't mention salt, but the Minhage Yeshurun didn't imply the Ibn Ezra mentioned anything about salt. He actually says that the Egyptian priests didn't consume salt, plus as the Ibn Ezra states, Egyptians in general didn't have eggs.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! When you can, could you please [edit] this post with a translation of this Ibn Ezra, for those readers who don't read Hebrew? If I'm understanding this correctly, it's as [rosends quoted in the comments](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/113319/eggs-in-salt-water-at-the-seder#comment377212_113319), and only says that they were vegetarian, nothing about salt.

Comment: If you look at the source carefully it never claims that the Ibn Ezra says anything about salt ,that is for a separate reason.