# After the Seder, can you give the shank bone to the dog?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, disposal, holy-objects

Serious question. In general, what are the laws or customs regarding the treatment of the items on the Seder plate? Are they to be considered commonplace or holy? Does it differ before and following their usage at the Seder? Should one differentiate between the items which we bless and consume, and those we don't?

Comment: I suspect this is related to how to handle common items used for a mitzvah after they have served that purpose.  For example, the vegetaion (palm branches, tree branches) I use for the shach on my succah.  After succos, I toss them.  Perhaps the same could be said for the items on the seder plate after the second seder?

Comment: One specific item from the _seder_ plate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6944

Answer (score 1):

I just read here:
https://halachablog.com/2016/04/13/the-shankbone-and-the-egg-at-the-seder/
that we actually eat it, since it was forbidden to leave it uneaten after a day.