# Is there a custom not to eat roasted chicken at the Seder?

Tags: minhag, food, passover-seder-hagada, meat, poultry

Does the custom to refrain from eating roasted meat at the Seder extend to chicken, turkey, and any other fowl one might serve roasted?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/629/5

Comment: Such is my family's practice.

Comment: We serve a one-pot stew (potatoes, meat, vegetables) which stays hot until you reach the point of the meal and does not require complex activities from my wife who also wants to hear the hagodo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch ([OC 476](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%95):2) writes that those who have the custom not to eat roasted meat on the Seder nights refrain from eating any type of meat that requires slaughtering,  including chicken.  Although the Korban Pesach could not be offered from such meat,  we are still concerned people may come to permit other types of roast.  However fish meat is permitted. (Shulchan Aruch Harav :3)

Answer (score 0):

In this shiur 49 minutes in he explains it:

http://www.torahanytime.com/scripts/media.php?file=media/Rabbi/Yosef_Viener/2010-03-14/Halachot_Pesach/Rabbi__Yossi_Viener__Halachot_Pesach__2010-03-14.wmv

He even quotes that the OU who he was a mashgiach for at some point and the argument he had based on it

Comment: Can you summarize what he says?