# What constitutes roasting with regard to Minhagim?

Tags: minhag, passover-seder-hagada

Roasting in Halachah generally refers to dry heat, such as broiling and barbequing.  But with respect to Minhagim, such as not eating roasted meat ([or poultry](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27077/5)) at the Seder, do we follow the same guidelines?  Are we less strict (like, do we say broiling in an oven doesn't really count because there's no flame)?  Are we more strict (like, do we say a pot roast is a roast)?

What about the standard "roasting pan", which has some liquid, and which is basted at regular intervals throughout the "roasting" process?

Comment: By "roasting pan", do you mean one with a partially raised bottom so that the food isn't sitting in liquid? If so, you may wish to describe it more fully in the question. And a source for your first sentence would be nice. But +1.

Comment: @msh210, I think our roasting pan has raised bumps at the bottom, but the meat definitely sits in its own juices once they start coming out of the meat.  I'll try to find a source to link to if I can.

Comment: Shouldn't the rule be the same as what was required/forbidden for the Korban Pesach, and not based on whatever English connotations those various words have?

Comment: @DoubleAA, so... only on a spit?

Comment: @SethJ At first I'd say yes, but perhaps the custom is to avoid all roasting not just fire-roasting as is required for pesach. So dry roasting on a material should be included as well. Compare the language of the Rambam in Hilchot Korban Pesach 8:11-12

Comment: btw broiling in an oven without a flame would not be allowed for Korban Pesach. (Pesachim 75a)

Comment: @DoubleAA I was about to reference [Pes. 74a](http://dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=pesachim&daf=74a&go=Go) and [RaMBa"M Hil. K"P 8:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/9108n.htm).

Comment: @DoubleAA (cont) So if you're going to derive it from K"P, that frees us up to do a lot of things. If you don't, then my question stands - what is roasting?

Comment: @SethJ I don't see why you are phrasing it like that. The laws of Korban Pesach define roasting nicely. It further subdivides roasting into fire-roasting and other-roasting. You can ask about other-roasting, but I don't see what the Hava Amina is for pot roast which is full of liquid even if it's called 'roast' in English.

Comment: @DoubleAA, fair enough re: pot roasting. But what about a roasting pan or "oven-roasted" chicken (usually using those 9x13" Pyrex® pans with no raised bumps at the bottom)?

Comment: @SethJ See the Rambam I quoted above :12

Comment: @DoubleAA, so the RaMBa"M likes his steak well done.

Comment: I think that cooking technique is called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braising

Answer (score 2):

The Magen Avraham (476:1), cited by Shulchan Aruch Harav (:4) and Mishna Berura (:1) writes that even "צלי קדר" (roasting in a pot with no other liquid besides it's own juice) is forbidden. Although the Korban Pesach was required to be "צלי אש" - roasted directly on the fire, even roasting in a dish on the Seder night is forbidden due to maaris ayin (concern what others might think). The Shu"t Pnei Melvin (Simon 123, cited by Nitey Gavriel vol. 2 96:3) extends this to frying as well,  based on the opinion of Pri Megadim who equates frying to roasting in other contexts.

Comment: Who's the Pnei Melvin?

Answer (score 0):

In this shiur 49 minutes in he explains it:

http://www.torahanytime.com/scripts/media.php?file=media/Rabbi/Yosef_Viener/2010-03-14/Halachot_Pesach/Rabbi__Yossi_Viener__Halachot_Pesach__2010-03-14.wmv