# "Roasted on fire" does not equal "oven roast". Why no "oven roast" for Seder?

Tags: minhag, passover-seder-hagada, meat

This is a follow up to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/629/custom-to-refrain-from-eating-meat-at-the-pesach-seder). The answer there explains that ther was confusion / concern about roast.

The verse regarding the Pesach lamb says:

Exodus 12:9:

כִּ֣י אִם־צְלִי־אֵ֔שׁ

but roast with fire

Sounds like "barbequed" meat or roasted directly on the fire. Most roasted meat nowadays, and I assume, then, when Taz wrote this was done in an oven or some other method that was not barbeque or roasted directly on a flame.

Now, may ovens are electric, yet many Ashkenazim would still consider meat cooked in **any** oven (except, perhaps, microwaved) as "roast".

My question is, considering that the cooking method used then and now is not the same as what is mentioned in the Torah, why was there any concern or confusion to begin with?

Comment: Not sure your title matches the body of the question.

Comment: What's the difference exactly? Both are direct dry heat.

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27101/759

Answer (score 4):

The Achronim (see for instance the Mishna Berurah in siman 476) addressed this quite clearly. The custom was to avoid confusion with the real sacrificial meat, and people aren't always that knowledgeable; so the custom became to avoid anything that the average person would call "roasted" as people might get confused -- even if it didn't meet the halachic definition of roasted. (The same folks who know the details of "roasted" would also know you absolutely no-way no-how can do a sacrifice outside of Jerusalem.)

Comment: +1 And they know the difference between a goat and a chicken, and yet we don't roast chicken either.

Comment: @user6591 yes, it was decided to draw the line at "anything that needs kosher slaughter."

Comment: This answer would be stronger with the addition of a citation of one of the Acharonim on this.