# Passing meats during maggid

Tags: halacha, passover-seder-hagada, meat

It says in pesachim that in the time of the beis hamikdash during maggid they would pass around small pieces of meats so the people are not starving. Is it still מותר to pass around meat?

Comment: I don't remember where I saw this, but I think I remember that at one point it used to be that maggid was at the end of the meal.

Comment: Sourcing where it says this in Pesachim would greatly improve this question's value

Comment: @ShmuelBrin At least the *mishnayos* are set in that order. If so, perhaps the OP is referring to ובמקדש היו מביאים לפניו גופו של פסח ([*Mishna Pesachim* 10:3](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99_%D7%92)), though that's not quite what's described in this question.

Comment: Maybe related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/629 ???